# Tagging versions in github repository

Tags: git, github

I would like to set a tag in my github repository to a specific commit.

I have a development pc which is making the commits to the repositories, and i have a server where i just pulling the changes.

In the server i set a tag to specific commit:

```
git tag -a v0.1.0 56886a
```

I would like to set that tag to my github repository without overwriting or merging any code or files in the repository. Keep in mind in that server i don't want to push or commit anything, just tag. How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You push tags with `git push --tags`. If you don't want to push from the server you need to tag from your dev machine (which IMO is what you should be doing anyway)